# Assign scientific notation to variable in Python

Tags: python, scientific-notation

I am trying to ask for a float variable, then assign its scientific notation to it and then use that notation in the following operations. As in, I want the program to actually work with the notation, not just return the results in it.
I managed to convert variable by using the print function:

```
def estim(abs(x)):
    a=print("{:.3e}".format(x))
    return a
```

However that does not actually assign the scientific value to x. I then tried

```
b=float(a)
```

but a is None type, so it doesn't work. Any help?

Edit: by scientific notation I mean X.YYYe+Z,
example: 31234.34234 -> 3.12e+04

Comment: Well, your code makes no sense. Maybe, `a="{:.3e}".format(x)` will work?

Comment: In Python `float`s don’t internally work using “decimal notation” or “scientific notation.”  These are only output formats. What do you mean by “work with the notation”?

Comment: I meant that instead of understading 44432.12, the program would consider it as 4.44*10^4, for instance, so actually 44400. @ForceBru ' s suggestion seems to work, thank you.

Comment: @L.R. `31234.34234 -> 3.12e+04` ... You need `a="{:.2e}".format(x)` and not `a="{:.3e}".format(x)`. (Now don't edit)

Comment: What is it you want to do with this number?  Scientific notation is a means of *displaying* a number.  It doesn't change what the number is.  So it only makes sense to "work with the number in scientific notation" if what you really want is to work with a string representation of it.

Comment: Yeah, I can't explain it very well... I'm really just trying to round the variable up to a certain number of significan figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `"{:.3e}".format(x)` you will get 3 digits after decimal, that is

```
>>> a = 31234.34234
>>> "{:.3e}".format(a)
'3.123e+04'
```

To get what you want, you need to do `"{:.2e}".format(x)`.

```
>>> "{:.2e}".format(a)
'3.12e+04'
>>> float("{:.2e}".format(a))
31200.0
```

Converting it back to `float` will give you the original value

As a function

```
def estim(x):
    x = abs(x)
    a=("{:.2e}".format(x))
    print(a)
    return a
```

Tip:

You can use `%` (It might be deprecated)

```
>>> a = 31234.34234
>>> "%e"%a
'3.123434e+04'
```

Comment: The code for the `estim` function you gave does not work: “SyntaxError: invalid syntax.”

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `a="{:.3e}".format(x)`

Here is an example

```
x=246789;
a="{:.3e}".format(x);
print a;
print float(a);
```

Output

```
2.468e+05
246800.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The returned value from a print is always None I suspect what you need is more along the lines of:

```
def estim(x):
    a="{:.3e}".format(abs(x))
    print a
    return a
```